# Перенос в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

```
.replace(/<div style="text-align: (.*?);">(.*?)<\/div>/gi, "123");
```

Проблема в том, что ищется строго `<div style="text-align: ...">text</div>`, а такой вариант не ищется:

```
<div style="text-align: ...">
 text
</div>
```

Как добавить в регулярное выражение возможность переноса строк?

Comment: [Не пытайтесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/276994) обрабатывать HTML регулярными выражениями. Подумайте о таком, например:

    <div style="text-align: ..."
    >
    <![CDATA[ </div> ]]>
    </div>

Возьмите лучше честный парсер, или работайте с DOM-моделью.

Comment: @VladD, ну ладно уж, когда надо по-быстрому что-то нагавнокодить, регулярные выражения сгодятся и для HTML.

Comment: @dzhioev: ну, если по-быстрому и не для себя, то можно :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению оба ответа в данном вопросе не правильные.

В JS метасимвол `.` всегда НЕ совпадает с литералом переноса строки.
Флаг `PCRE_S_DOTALL` отсутствует.

Негласно принято вместо `.` в таких ситуациях писать `[\s\S]` это позволит захватить все символы , включая перенос строки.

Если Вы гонитесь за микросекундами производительности, то лучше писать так: `[^]` - это самый производительный вариант из всех возможных.

П.С. Делаю некроответ, потому что люди, оказывается, приходят в этот вопрос из поиска, а тут два заблуждения, причем одно принято как правильное.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте (.*?) заменить на (.*)?

Comment: @Arc, не совсем понял, что Вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: /<div style="text-align: (.\*?);">(.*?)<\/div>/  
вы используете конструкцию (.\*?). Это не хорошо. замените ее на (.\*)?

Comment: @Arc, заменил. Но переносы всё равно не фиксируются.

Comment: /<div style="text-align: (.*)">(.*)<\/div>/si  
рабочая регулярка

Answer (score 1):

Пару вариантов:

```
.replace(/<div style="text-align: (.*?);">[^<]*<\/div>/gi, "123");
.replace(/<div style="text-align: (.*?);">[^<]+<\/div>/gi, "123");
```

Так работает?

Comment: @manking, да уже сделал. Всё равно + в карму :)