# Как в регулярном выражении игнорировать символ переноса строки - \n

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, сопоставление-с-образцом

Нужно между тегами заменить **е** на **Ё** и **z** на **Z**, например.

```
    String s= "<pre><code>еееееееееееzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</code></pre>";
    String startTag = "<pre><code>";
    String endTag = "</code></pre>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(startTag + "(.*?)" + endTag);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        s = s.replace(matcher.group(0), startTag + matcher.group(1).replace("z", "Z").replace("е", "Ё") + endTag);
    }

    System.out.println("\nПосле изменения: \n" + s);
```

Выводит всё корректно:

```
<pre><code>ЁЁЁЁЁЁЁЁЁЁЁZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</code></pre>
```

СтОит же в условии (в переменную **s**) добавить **\n** в любом месте, как реализация перестаёт работать:

```
        s= "<pre><code>ееее\nеееееееzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</code></pre>";
```

выдаст:

```
<pre><code>ееее
еееееееzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</code></pre>
```

т.е. - без изменений.
Что я делаю не так? Не соображу.

- На этом сайте нашел похожую статью ([Перенос в регулярном выражении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/247151/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)), но ответы не проконали.

Comment: Написал ответ в вопросе, на который Вы ссылаетесь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте флаг `PCRE_S_DOTALL`.
По умолчанию метасимвол `.` не включает в себя перенос строки и только применение данного флага включает совпадение `.` с литералом переноса строки.

```
Pattern.compile( regex, Pattern.S );
Pattern.compile( regex, Pattern.DOTALL );
```

Оба варианта равносильны.

Comment: Респектище, амиго!!! Больше недели бьюсь с этим вопросом, уже в многопоточку залез..., а делов-то на копейку! В одну строку! Спасибо!!!  ...........................Авось, кому пригодится: ....................... `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(startTag + "(.*?)" + endTag, Pattern.DOTALL);`